# If I'm using bitbucket.org does that mean i don't need to know how to use git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm confused about git and bitbucket - if I am using bitbucket does it mean I don't need to know git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is source code hosting platform. You must know [**git**](http://git-scm.com/) or [**hg**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) to be able to push or send your code over to BitBucket.

In essence, BitBucket acts as a remote origin for your local git/hg repository. It's a lot more powerful than just dumping your code. For example, other people can fork your repository by just clicking a button. They can view the entire commit history and all your branches.

Comment: "remote origin" is git-specific slang. Try to avoid it in common questions

Comment: @LazyBadger = The question is tagged git ( the BB tag was actually added by me) This is not a common question.

Comment: "BitBucket acts as a remote origin for your local git/hg repository" - hg mentioned, there it isn't aplicable

Answer (score 1):

BitBucket can be thought to be the server hosting your repo - be it hg or git. You need to know atleast some basics of Git, like clone, push etc. to work with it. You can work with command line or GUI like TortoiseGit, and host it on BitBucket, that is a parallel question, but you must know about git.

Comment: need know git in order to work with BB?! It's fud. Everybody can use BB in pure mercurial mode and know ***nothing** about git

Comment: @LazyBadger - What are you talking about? The OP asks about git and BB.

Comment: well, question was not transparent on our interpretation. I know - BB can server both hg and git, it is possible to  use BB without git... thus - I hated your statement, which I read as I read